# Elasticsearch BoolQuery Gets Different Files

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

hi i am trying to do a search where i can find specific files using elastic search. This is my java client:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I prepared a query as follows:

```
private static Query getQueryByStatus() {
        BoolQuery boolQuery = BoolQuery.of(b -> b
            .should(qb -> qb.match(m -> m.field("fileType").query("WAIT_EXP")))
            .should(qb -> qb.match(m -> m.field("fileType").query("EXP")))
        );

        return boolQuery._toQuery();
    }
```

```
Query testQuery = getQueryByStatus();

                        response = client.search(s -> s
                                .index(fileIndex)
                                .from(filterDto.getPage() * filterDto.getSize())
                                .size(filterDto.getSize())
                                .query(q -> q
                                    .bool(b -> b
                                        .must(matchCompany)
                                        .must(matchByWords)
                                        .should(testQuery) 
                                    )
                                ),
                            SearchData.class
                        );
```

My expectation here is that it finds files with filetype exp or wait_exp, but elastic brings them as well as unrelated files. Unfortunately, I could not see any clear explanation on the subject in the client's [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/searching.html) I used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on above code i can see you are doing a must match even when you want to get the search based on file names.

You can use match_phrase_prefix type of query if you want to bring in the file that are starting with "WAIT_EXP*" & "EXP*"

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html

Comment: im storing the search data as class and file type is inside the class here is the file: `private Date annunciationDate;
    private FileType fileType; 
    private String personName` and my FileType is an enum that contains the types WAIT_EXP, EXP etc.

Comment: @levent i think then you should use match_phrase to find the files specific FileType with the names "WAIT_EXP" and "EXP"

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html